# Method Attributes in C#: Check access permission before method call

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I've written an asp.net mvc application in C# using the [Authorize] Attribute for permission management. Now I want to add an own additional attribute to check further self created permissions, for example a [HasTheRight] attribute which allows access if a defined method returns true.

Comment: Sounds wonderful. So what do you want to know?

Answer (score 0):

your going to need to write your own authorize attribue

this new attribute class with inherit `ActionFilterAttribute` and implement the interface `IActionFilter`

there is a full tutorial from Microsoft [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-custom-action-filters) on writing custome attributes